# Xcode 11 - ld warning about building for iOS but object file built for free standing

Tags: xcode, warnings, ld

I have a moderate-sized project that's been building for a long time with no warnings. Today I updated to Xcode 11, and suddenly I'm getting hundreds of warnings that look like:

```
ld: warning: building for iOS, but linking in object file (/Users/<username>/dev/<project directory>/build/target/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/<target directory>/BuildProductsPath/Debug-iphoneos/<libName>.a(<object file name>.o)) built for free standing
```

These warnings appear for each and every object file in this library, and moreover, they appear twice. Most disturbing of all, when this is all complete, there is the following line in the output:

```
error: the following command failed with exit code 0 but produced no further output
Ld /Users/<username>/dev/<project directory>/build/target/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/<target directory>>/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/<target name>.build/Debug-iphoneos/<targetname>.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Binary/<target name> normal arm64
```

The build then succeeds and produces what looks like a normal output. The result runs, but I have a stiff time ahead of me to do a regression test to see if it doesn't crash in some cases now. I mention again that I've never seen this warning before, much less hundreds of times - only with Xcode 11 (and 11.1 GM seed).

Anybody know (a) whether this is dangerous, and (b) how to stop this warning?

UPDATE: It looks like most or all of the files in question are part of OpenSSL. Anybody else seen this?